# Problems with HttpClient on WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Please tell me why it works only once?
I want to create a button to update the time, but my app only shows me the first time I got

```
    public async void q()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://cleverapps.ru/wp.php");
        string getResponsestring = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        MessageBox.Show(getResponsestring);
    }

    private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        q();
    }
```

Comment: I think the `MessageBox.Show` will not appear in the `async` method.

Comment: Your problem isnt clear. Only first time what? It only shows the messagebox for the first click? Is that what you mean?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov,"It only shows the messagebox for the first click?" No, messagebox always shows, but the line was always the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably happens because caching is enabled by default.

Try adding the following line before making the GetAsync call:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.IfModifiedSince = DateTime.UtcNow;
```